# Azure Bot is not running on Skype

Tags: azure, botframework, bots, skype

I have deployed My Azure Web App Bot on Azure Portal. and also I have deployed it on Skype via channel. but whenever I click on Skype Channel, Bot is not getting run.

screenshot:

[image]

when I click on Skype Channel, it will redirect to join.skype.com site.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot you provided looks like you bot is up for review. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skype?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Comment: Can you provide me with your AppId (no passwords or keys, please)? This will make it easier to diagnose what might be happening. And can you tell me what Skype client you are using (Skype for desktop, Skype UWP, etc.)? Also what browser and OS?

Comment: AppId:68507a28-9e4b-4175-9282-c668c54cf940
I am using only Skype..and browser is Chrome.

Comment: You might also try editing and saving your bot registration settings for the skype channel and make some small change in description or something.  Sometimes that resets the relationship between Bot Service and Skype.

Comment: Hi @SachinPatil, this is a known issue that is effecting some bots. I do not have a timeframe, but it is actively being investigated for a solution.